# Qt applications how to structure not to have all slots in MainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, design-patterns, architecture, signals-slots

In my Qt applications I typically tend to write all slots within the MainWindow class.

I'm using many manipulation of QSliders, QTextEdits and lots of QFormLayouts whose values influence status of other widgets (QGLWidget typically), controlled from within my MainWindow.

I admit I hate to do connection manually on each and every object within specialized methods of my MainWindow, this results in more than 2000 lines of code but it is very practical as from MainWindow I can access the UI.

I cannot imagine large scale applications are relegating all the methods within the MainWindow.

Are there some hints from software engineering to structure Qt applications in some smarter way?

Comment: If your widgets are custom defined, then you can define yours slots specific to each widget within their class. You need to understand the privacy of your widgets for a proper implementation. If you are able to change anything and everything from your `MainWindow` class, then what you're doing might work but necessarily good. In other words, do not have more public variables than you actually need. The widget should have control over its own parameters - more than `MainWindow` class.

Comment: Look at the Qt Model/View framework http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modelview.html

Comment: Split your GUI into widgets each of which can have its own widgets and handle their signals.